# Linuxmint 20.3: Update Manager won't start

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, curl, software-updates

Unable to start Update Manager from GUI or from terminal. Any suggestions?

```bsh
$ mintupdate
$ Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/mintUpdate.py", line 18, in <module>
import pycurl
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.68.0) is older than compile-time version (7.79.0)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 153, in apport_excepthook
with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/crash/_usr_lib_linuxmint_mintUpdate_mintUpdate.py.1000.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/mintUpdate.py", line 18, in <module>
import pycurl
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.68.0) is older than compile-time version (7.79.0)
```

---

System information

System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-92-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7 Distro: Linux Mint 20.3 Una base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Comment: sudo apt install python-pycurl

Comment: @dcom-launch Didn't help even after a reboot. Same error.